# Pandas | Make a summary table with multiple criteria per value

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to make a summary table like this:

[image]

From this dataset:

```py
pd.DataFrame(data={"grade":[10,5,9,7],
                   "sex": ["F", "F", "M", "M"],
                   "pred_1": [1,0,1,1], 
                   "pred_2": [0,0,1,1],
                   "pred_3": [0,0,0,1]})
```

| grade | sex | pred_1 | pred_2 | pred_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | F | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 5 | F | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 9 | M | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 7 | M | 1 | 1 | 1 |

I'm not asking for the hole code, but some help on how to apply different functions to each column while pivoting and grouping. Like:

```py
pd.pivot_table(df, values=pred_cols, index=["sex"] )
```

Gives gives me the "sex" data that i'm looking for. But how can I concatenate different aggs, crating some "new indices" like the ones I've showed in the picture above ("mean_grade", "min_grade", etc) and generate a single table.

Thank you in adnvance.

Comment: Can you make an output that matches your given input ?

Comment: @Timeless by output do you mean a picture like the one I've sheared but with values that respect the ones of the original dataset? I.e. the real max_grade value for each column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach: creating two separate `dfs`, which we then concatenate using [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df_filter = df.filter(like='pred').mul(df.grade, axis=0).replace(0,np.nan)

df_sex = df_filter.groupby(df.sex).count()
df_sex = df_sex.div(df_sex.sum(axis=0))

dic = {'mean': 'mean_grade',
       'min': 'min_grade',
       'max': 'max_grade',
       'std': 'estandar_dev_grades',
       'F': 'Females',
       'M': 'Males',
       'count': 'Count_pred == 1'}

res = (pd.concat([df_filter.describe(), df_sex])
       .reindex(dic)
       .rename(dic)
       )
    
res
                        pred_1    pred_2  pred_3
mean_grade            8.666667  8.000000     7.0
min_grade             7.000000  7.000000     7.0
max_grade            10.000000  9.000000     7.0
estandar_dev_grades   1.527525  1.414214     NaN
Females               0.333333  0.000000     0.0
Males                 0.666667  1.000000     1.0
Count_pred == 1       3.000000  2.000000     1.0
```

**Explanation**

- `df_filter`: select the `"pred_"` columns using [`df.filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html), multiply by `df.grade` ([`df.mul`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html)) and replace zeros with `np.nan` ([`df.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html)).
- `df_sex`: apply [`df.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to `df_filter` and apply [`count`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.count.html). Next, divide result by the sum of the columns ([`df.div`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.div.html), [`df.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html)).
- Prepare a dictionary (here named: `dic`) to rename the index values.
- Now, we want to apply `pd.concat`. For `df_filter`, chain [`df.describe`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.describe.html), which will get us `'mean','min','max','std','count'` (as well as `'percentiles'`, but the reindex below will filter them out).
- Finally, we chain [`df.reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) and [`df.rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html), both times with `dic` as input, sorting the index values, and removing ones that are not found in the dictionary keys, and then renaming them to the dictionary values.

*Note:* instead of `df.describe` you can also use [`df.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html) with `'mean'`, etc.

Comment: Thanks! That's basically what I was looking for. I will still look for other approaches that make it in less steps and promote automation of this process, that is what i'm really looking for.

Comment: Me again, how would you assign the values of `df.grade` without using `.mul` and replacing zeros? I refer to `.mul(df.grade, axis=0).replace(0,np.nan)`
Can't you simply assign them element wise with other function?

Comment: I can think of this alternative: `cols = [col for col in df if col.startswith('pred')]`, `df.loc[:, cols] = np.where(df[cols].eq(1), np.tile(df.grade, (3,1)).transpose(), np.nan)`, but that would basically have the same performance, and I'd say you lose on readability. Doing this: `df.filter(like='pred').astype(bool).apply(lambda x: df.grade[x])` is definitely much slower. But I also don't see the problem with using `mul`, to be honest. Does the job :). Good luck with the project.